# How to merge flowfiles in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

[image]I have   several  flowfile with the  same name( in my  case  it  can be  date) i want  to merge  together  flowfiles  with the  same name i tried  to  use mergecontent and increased  minimumGroupSize to 10 kb and  even   increased maximum   number of  bins  but nothing  helps I  got  this:
[image]

instead  of  one  flowfile  with the same  name,  what  should i  do?

Comment: please attach to you question all properties of your mergecontent processor. the very important for you is `Correlation Attribute Name = filename`

Comment: I have  added  configuration , i  use   filename  attribute like  this  ${filename}

Comment: I have  tried  this  version  too Correlation Attribute Name = filename but it  didn't  help me  can  you reccomend  me any nifi processor  which can  help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group flowfiles by values in attribute `filename` then you have to set property `Correlation Attribute Name` to `filename`